# What kind of being was Huwawa?

Tags: sumerian, gilgamesh, humbaba

Humbaba was the guardian of the Cedar Forest and was fought by Gilgamesh.

Some say Humbaba is a monstrous giant and some say he was a dangerous mechanical monster (like a robot).

For example in [Flying Serpents and Dragons by R. A. Boulay](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2TtOjwtbXG8C&pg=PA256&lpg=PA256&dq=Humbaba#v=onepage&q=Humbaba&f=false) we can read:

[image]

Is it true that he was a robot? If it's not, what kind of being he/it was?

Comment: I just laughed so hard that coffee snorted up my nose. I was a bit uncredulous at "launch platform" but "rocket preparation building at Baalbek" and "launch tower" sounds like serious business. Is this meant persiflage that textual interpretation may be *a little* arbitrary? Boats seems like a more probable interpretation. This comment is meant to serve discoverability, because images are hardly accessible to search engines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: Clay Mask of Huwawa]

*Clay mask of the demon Huwawa, [The British Museum](http://www.britishmuseum.org/explore/highlights/highlight_objects/me/c/clay_mask_of_the_demon_huwawa.aspx). From Sippar, southern Iraq, about 1800-1600 BC.*

Huwawa was a demonic creature, of neither mortal nor godly origin, created by Enlil to guard the forest of Lebanon :

> I never knew a mother who bore me, nor a father who brought me up! I was born in the mountains...

He is described in *[The Epic of Gilgamesh](http://www.ancienttexts.org/library/mesopotamian/gilgamesh/tab2.htm)*, tablet 2, as:

> Humbaba's roar is a flood, his mouth is death and his breath is fire! He can hear a hundred leagues away any [rustling?] in his forest!

He was not, however, a mechanical creature such as a robot, as such things did not exist in Ancient Mesopotamia. He had human characteristics, and a physical body which Gilgamesh could capture:

> they pulled out his insides including his tongue.
>
> (tablet 5, *[The Epic of Gilgamesh](http://www.ancienttexts.org/library/mesopotamian/gilgamesh/tab5.htm)*)

And:

> Huwawa bared his teeth at him [...] He tied up his arms like a captured man [...] Huwawa sat down and began to weep, shedding tears...

He is also easily slayed by Enkidu:

> Enkidu, full of rage and anger, cut his throat...

Furthermore, Enlil adds further evidence to Huwawa's mortal characteristics when, upset by Huwawa's death, he cries out:

> He should have eaten the bread that you eat, and should have drunk the water that you drink.
>
> (all quotes from *[Gilgamesh and Huwawa](http://etcsl.orinst.ox.ac.uk/section1/tr1815.htm)* unless mentioned)

He appears, then, to be a monstrous but mortal creature. Parallels have been drawn between the stories of Huwawa and Medusa(1), because of their similarities of a hero beheading a demonic creature.

---

Source:

1. Clark Hopkins, "Assyrian elements in the Perseus–Gorgon story," American Journal of Archaeology 38 (1934:341-ff)